# Simple C: How do I scan this information in properly?

Tags: c

OK this is a simple question but for some reason I just can't get it right. I have to scan from a file hundreds of lines of code and store it in a array (which I can normally do a ok job with) however At one point the code will specify a number that then corresponds to the next batch of chars ints and floats going into various arrays.

As I know I am not describing this correctly here is a example.

one line of the file I am reading will contain something close to this.

> 0221 T 2 S P 850 150 0.90 0.75 500 24 2 2012 G A 7 9600.00 0.1 1000 Name_of_place
>
> 0104 L 1 F 400 1.00 0.75 500 24 2 2012 G A 7 9600.00 0.1 1000 Ballroom

the problem I am having is This part here

> 0221 T **2 S P 850 150** 0.90 0.75 500 24 2 2012 G A 7 9600.00 0.1 1000 Name_of_place
>
> 0104 L **1 F 400** 1.00 0.75 500 24 2 2012 G A 7 9600.00 0.1 1000 Ballroom

The rest after this is Generally the exact same however at this point the number at the front descides all the values that are going in. I am almost completely lost on how to write a way that can scan this and store the data into arrays correctly

Comment: This is a design question (I see no code here) so is perfectly on topic for us.

Comment: Each field on your input must have a meaning that you should know about. If you care to share that, it will make understanding your problem easier.

Comment: alright The entire thing is about venues. The first number is a code(dictating a place Like a P.O.box) then the second number is a type(T stands Theater) The bold number and the following are the parts I am confused about they deal with the Number of seating types the seating types the ammount of seats they hold how much they are expected to sell on a discount and how much they are expected to sell at normal price. the rest is hourly rate of venue. then the day month year of event type of event, size type. lengthin hours of event. fixed and precentage profit and name.

Comment: @Doc: can you tell us that in your question then?

Comment: My problem is that I have to scan both lines of code and have it input correctly into the arrays. however the lines are not fixed and CANNOT be fixed so I have to have it where it uses fscanf and reads both of these lines and inputs the data correctly.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to scan each line into an appropriately sized buffer using `fgets`:

```
fgets(buffer, BufferSize, fp);
```

and then [use the string tokenizer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/):

```
char* pch = strtok(buffer, " ");
venue.code = atoi(pch);
pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
venue.type = pch[0];
pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
venue.numberOfSeatingTypes = atoi(pch);
```

Once you've grabbed the sizes of the variable bits, you can then `malloc` space for them:

```
venue.seatingTypes = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * venue.numberOfSeatingTypes);
venue.seatingSize = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * venue.numberOfSeatingTypes);
```

And then continue using the string tokenizer in a loop to get the variable seating types and size of each type.

Be aware that the string tokenizer is not re-entrant, so you may be better off using the [re-entrant version.](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strtok_r.3.asp)

Comment: re-entrant functions do not seem to be a requirement by the OP, nor would they seem to be needed for a valid solution to the problem.

Comment: @GregA.Woods: Sure!  But you're better off avoiding them. People tend to get into the habit of using the non-reentrant ones, and then wonder why the "same" solution fails in another case where reentrancy is important.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's line-oriented, I'd start by reading a line (e.g., with `fgets`).

Then I'd parse out the individual items in a line using `sscanf`. At least if I'm understanding correctly, you need to scan the first three (or so) fields, then based on the contents of (some of?) those, decide how to parse the rest of the line. That's, again, fairly straightforward. Just read in N fields (N=3, I think), then you'd do something like:

```
switch (venue_type) {
    case 'S':
        // read whatever
    case 'F'
        // read stuff for ballroom
    case 'T':
        // read stuff for theater
}
```

It may be easiest to re-read the line from the beginning for each type of venue, rather than trying to continue after the third (or so) field that you've already read.